# Are points $(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1$ which satisfy $X\subset V(af+bg)$ closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, moduli-space

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^m_k$ be a closed irreducible subvariety, and $f,g\in k[x_0,\dots,x_m]$ be homogenous polynomials of $\deg f=\deg g$.

Then we have parametrized hypersurfaces $V(af+bg)\subset \mathbb{P}^m$ for $(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1$.

Is the following subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$ closed in the Zariski topology?

$\{(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1~|~ X\subset V(af+bg)\}$

Moreover if it is true, how is this proposition generalized?

Comment: closed in $\mathbf{P}^1$ means just finitely many points. If there are no further assumptions on $X$ (could be just a point) then I don't know if you can say something